# How can I highlight the significance the last item in my list of examples?

Tags: adjectives

I am in the middle of writing a paper, and I want to highlight the importance of "learning" in the following sentence.

> Nowadays, we use our mobile phones for different purposes:
> communicating with friends and relatives, transportation, shopping, and
> **learning**.

Is there any way to attract readers' attention to learning in this list of examples?

To be honest, I was thinking about saying "and more prominently learning", or something like that but then I think that the most prominent application of mobile phones is for communication. Any suggestions for me? Thank you

Comment: "as well as for learning"?

Comment: By placing the most important item first in the list? The sentence makes little sense though: "Nowadays, we use our mobile phones for different purposes:" yet the first item is exactly what we have always used them for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression "*not least*" is useful to single out the term that follow it as special,  important, noteworthy.

- Nowadays, we use our mobile phones for different purposes: communicating with friends and relatives, transportation, shopping, and *not least*, learning.

> ([FreeDictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+least)) **not least** notably; in particular.

Answer (score 3):

In your particular case, since the element you wish to emphasise is the last on your list, it is common to use the expression ***last but not least***, which means:

> importantly, despite being mentioned after everyone else; despite being mentioned at the end:
>
> - I would like to thank my publisher, my editor, and ***, last but not least,*** my husband.([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/last-but-not-least))

You can use it as an aside, between commas (before *last* and after *least*), or only with one comma after *least*:

> The television is big, has an excellent picture, ***and last but not least,*** it's cheap.([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/last%20but%20not%20least))

Answer (score 2):

You could set traditional use(s) apart from newer ones, and emphasize the last with an adverb, something like:

> Nowadays, we use our mobile phones **not only** for communicating with
> friends and relatives, **but also** for transportation, shopping, and
> **especially/particularly** learning.

(or *.... and learning in particular.*)

**particularly**

> 3 : in particular : SPECIFICALLY
> *The tools were useful, particularly the knife.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/particularly)